# nodejs configuration using (*.p2f) file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse, enide

I am newbie to nodejs environment. I just started learning about nodejs but I got stuck with environment set up.

When I am trying to set up the environment using *.p2f file which i downloaded from eclipse market place support site for nodejs, I am getting  following errors

[image: nodejs-eclipse issue]

Help me to sort out the problem

[image]

configuration problem using .p2f file in Node Tool Suit

Comment: http://blog.christoffer.me/post/2012-07-29-how-to-run-nodejs-application-in-eclipse/#.UwNCVPmSySo

Comment: http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2013/04/nodejs-programming-in-eclipse.html

Comment: You could try any of the URL's to get it working
http://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/configuring-eclipse-to-run-standalone-javascript-files-using-node-jsgoogle-v8-engine/

Comment: I was able to run hello world by following your first option, but that was not answer to question,

Answer (score 0):

You have got Enide .p2f file, that should be used in Eclipse as File -> Import -> Install -> Install Software Items from File. (All instructions are inside .p2f file, that you can open with text editor. It is just XML file )

Actually, Nodeclipse project download page http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ has a lot of options to get started with Node.js and Eclipse.

- You can download Enide Studio wit ready to go plugin set.
- Or Install Nodeclipse plugin into any Eclipse based IDE.

select what option would work for you.

@Dot_NET Junior please raise an issue on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/ if you are still interested in created solution with Node.js and Eclipse

Comment: as per your suggestion I installed the Node Tool Suit, but I don't know whether I have to do any more modification using .p2f file or not. But I tried to do so and got error which I posted below my updated question. @paul