# Upgrading to latest nodejs from nodejs 0.8 using npm command

Tags: node.js

I was trying to install nodejs using the node-v0.10.25-x86.msi windows installer but getting the following error[image]

I was able to install node.js 0.8 version, is there any way to upgrade to latest version

Comment: try installing the older version. There are always problems installing latest version

Comment: Ok I have 1 try this.
Edit the package.json and change the version of express to something like 0.8.1 and save and close the file.
then try npm install

Comment: Try this
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"

then npm install -g express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a similar issue. Try installing this one

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/

It solved my problem. It is very stable version.

Comment: thanks for your support, it is working. I have also some problem nodejs in eclipse environment, I am sharing the link to question which is in SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846023/nodejs-configuration-using-p2f-file-in-eclipse

Comment: @Sudip7 I am looking into it now. Please mark my answer thanks

Comment: also if there is any other way to configure nodejs in eclipse then let me know, it will be helpful

Comment: I have'nt used node.js with eclipse. Netbeans is always an option for me but let me have a look if i can find a way.

You could try
Jetbrains
Netbeans

Comment: my helloworld example worked properly when I tried use npm install -g express  I am facing some error which I am putting in my question above in the form of log

Comment: Ok Can you paste the error. are you behind any proxy network ??

Comment: I am using my terminal assigned to me and using company provided LAN

Comment: I had an issue when installing express framework behind the proxy network. If you have proxy look at the commands
http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Also try changing the version of express in npm install express 0.8

Comment: I tried your  command before and after setting the proxy, the result is same, I am still getting the same error

Comment: is there any way to upgrade my nodejs version from 0.8 to latest