# Any suggestions how to install grunt in windows behind a proxy?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to install grunt on a windows machine that is behind a corporate proxy.

I have installed node and npm, I can see the versions of both of them from the command line. But when I try to install grunt as is described in the grunt site http://gruntjs.com/getting-started but I get the following errors and I can't figure it out how to solve it.

Here is the Error message I get:

```
npm.cmd: npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
At line:1 char:4 + npm <<<< install -g grunt-cli + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified:
(npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId: 
NativeCommandError

npm ERR! at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1367:32), npm ERR! at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17), npm ERR! at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:979:10), npm ERR! at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:471:13), npm ERR! at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:340:10), npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:368:25)
npm ERR! at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:225:10), npm ERR! at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:215:5), npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:182:11), npm ERR! at at write (_stream_readable.js:601:24), npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log, npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at: npm ERR! <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>, npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601, npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR!cwd C:\Dev\gruntTest2, npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31, npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
```

I am using visual studio 2013. I have tried installing direct from the command line and from the Package Manager Console, and basically I get the same error.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to install grunt or anything else from npm, first I need to use the following command:

npm config set strict-ssl false

I found this answer in different places around stackoverflow and other sites. But I used as a reference [Ramesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855035/ssl-error-cert-untrusted-while-using-npm-command) answer. I also include the proxy address of the network, but that didn't work until I change strict-ssl configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a proxy on your own system  ( fiddler can function as a proxy)

and point your browser proxy settings  to this proxy.

Because fiddler is started under your credentials, proxy authentication is no longer a problem.

Remember to restart programs after you change the proxy settings

Comment: sorry I don't understand your answer. How fiddler will help? For the error I understand that some kind of certification is untrusted: **Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED** Could you explain your answer?