# Node.js npm install express - can't install express, error CERT_UNTRUSTED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to install express on Raspberry Pi because I wanto to use it for REST API. The problem is that I get following message and any solution that I found on this site doesn't work.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:525:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:192:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1582:7)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1485:20)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:544:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:898:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:285:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.62-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/myapp
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.11
npm ERR! code ESSL
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.14.62-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/myapp
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.11
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/myapp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here are some commands that people asked about in other threads :

> npm version

```
http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.8.21',
  v8: '3.11.10.25',
  ares: '1.7.5-DEV',
  uv: '0.8',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  openssl: '1.0.0f',
  npm: '1.2.11' }
```

> npm list

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/myapp $ npm list
/usr/local/myapp
└── (empty)
```

I also tried to clear cache but nothing works and I'm stuck. 
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error: CERT\_UNTRUSTED while using npm command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855035/ssl-error-cert-untrusted-while-using-npm-command)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm config set ca ""
```