# npm Syntaxerror: unexpected Identifier

Tags: node.js, json, git, ubuntu, npm

Goodday, I ve been working on a project and had to install git, nodejs, npm. My OS is ubuntu 18. I ran into alot of errors and I will describe the steps I took, since one of them made me trip and fall down really hard. And showed me that it is without help not fixable. Back to topic, the steps were (terminal):

1. installing git -> led to the error:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point
>   /home/ubuntuadmin) Stopping at filesystem boundary
>   (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

;

2. installed npm (without nodejs) -> tried to run npm within the
   folder of project -> Error occured:

> serverless offline start
>
> sh: 1: serverless: not found npm ERR! weird error 127 npm WARN This
>   failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" npm WARN For
>   further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
>
> 3) I installed npm modules and this error occured:
>
> npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
>
> npm ERR! at SecurePair. (tls.js:1370:32)
>
> npm ERR! at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
>
> npm ERR! at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
>
> npm ERR! at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
>
> npm ERR! at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
>
> npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
>
> npm ERR! at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
>
> npm ERR! at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
>
> npm ERR! at EncryptedStream.Writable.write
>   (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
>
> npm ERR! at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
>
> npm ERR! at flow (_stream_readable.js:592:7)
>
> npm ERR! at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:624:5)
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>
> npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! or email it to:
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-137-generic
>
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
>
> npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntuadmin/goldpreis-api
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! /home/ubuntuadmin/goldpreis-api/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

3.1) I fixed the errors from 3 and now only WARN occure. But after I typed `npm start`, this error poped up:

> goldpreis-api@1.0.0 start /home/ubuntuadmin/goldpreis-api
>
> serverless offline start
>
> sh: 1: serverless: not found
>
> npm ERR! weird error 127
>
> npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>
> npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>
> /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

4)then I tried: `npm i -D serverless` which led to `npm ERR! Error: EACCES`(lost the rest of the error code) -> then googled that one and found an answere there: [Eacces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied)

->that led to an error after running npm install: [...]
npm warn unmet dependencies [...] (googled them and found this:[npm warn unmet dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies#20765400))

4.1) After trying to fix it and failed with error . I tried looking it up and googling it I found a post on stackoverflow (link: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855035/ssl-error-cert-untrusted-while-using-npm-command#22526046))

4.2)The creating or bypassing of package.json didnt work so I googled it and went to the website: [doc.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)
-> this brought up the error:

> ubuntuadmin@ubuntuadmin:~/goldpreis-api$ npm status
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
>
> let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
>             ^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>
> at startup (node.js:119:16)
>
> at node.js:902:3

Doesn't matter what I write in the terminal `ie:npm, npm start, npm status` it always showes up.
Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: try to install `nvm` first and with it, you can install any `node` version.

Comment: hello mohammad, i have already installed nvm. But for some reason when i type `sudo apt-get install nvm` in the ubuntu terminal it showes `E: unable to locate package nvm`

Comment: hi, you should use this Github repo to install `nvm` `https://github.com/creationix/nvm`

Comment: hey mohammad, ive almost finished this article until i reached the test section.  when i try npm install`the syntaxerror appears (the last error message).

Comment: look, in this situations, I always remove everything (the software that not working) and install it again, I think you have installed some software before and these errors are because your old software and the new one are conflicts. maybe I'm wrong . but if you remove it and install it again and error exist, try to reinstall your os, and I say again. maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: well the error has been removed. it was  a conflict within the programm, i reinstalled everything. my mistake was to use "sudo"-command and non-sudo. but now its working fine. thanks anyways.