# I am having a trouble in installing angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am getting this error while installing angular . I think may be its a problem of path of npm , but how to solve it .
I did with root permission also then also got error of certificated untrusted. Error below -

```
 root@Aishwarya:/# npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "angular-cli"
    root@Aishwarya:/# npm install -g angular-cli
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
    npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
    npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
    npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
    npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
    npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
    npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR! or email it to:
    npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

    npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-35-generic
    npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
    npm ERR! cwd /
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
    root@Aishwarya:/#
```

Comment: Hello Aishwarya - I think you stand a better chance of an answer if you tag this with `npm` rather than `javascript`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a network issue if you are using Linux then;

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If windows then restarting your PC should solve this.

It could also be git version issue or node version issue if thats the issue then:

- Uninstall Git, Node.js, npm
- Install Git
- Install Node.js witn npm
- Install angular

Or simply the following could also solve the issue:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g rxjs
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Not working, still the same error. I uninstalled npm and again installed it but after that also having same error

Comment: Are you using some company proxy?ping github.com, if ping failed. it is DNS error.

Comment: ping is not failed . I did with root permission also then also got error. Check my edited question

Comment: I think you are in corporate proxy.You can bypass the ssl using:                        
**npm config set strict-ssl false**
Here is more insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855035/ssl-error-cert-untrusted-while-using-npm-command